# Find # of rows of Tabulator table

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, tabulator

I have a table on a website that I made using Tabulator. Is there a way to get the # of rows of the table at any moment. Such as table.size or table.length?

table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
height:405,
paginationSize:50,
pagination:"local",
data:tabledata, columns: [...]});

Answer (score 2):

Check if this helps your problem:

**Javascript:**

```
var tabulator_table = new Tabulator("#example", {
    columns: [
        { title: "", field: "", bottomCalc: "count", headerFilter: "input" },
        { title: "", field: "", bottomCalc: "count", headerFilter: "input" },
        { title: "", field: "", bottomCalc: "count", headerFilter: "input" },
        { title: "", field: "", bottomCalc: "count",headerFilter: "input" },
        { title: "", field: "", bottomCalc: "count", headerFilter: "input" },
        { title: "", field: "", bottomCalc: "count", headerFilter: "input" },
    ],
    dataFiltered: function(filters, rows) {
        var el = document.getElementById("search_count");
        el.innerHTML = rows.length;
    },
    dataLoaded: function(data) {
        var el = document.getElementById("total_count");
        el.innerHTML = data.length;
    },
});

var total_count = $(".tabulator-footer").find('.tabulator-cell:first-child()').text();
$("#total_count").text(total_count);
//rest of your js if you have any.
```

**CSS:**

```
.tabulator-footer {
    display: none;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<span style="color:#102D4F;font-size:12px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
  Showing <span id="search_count"></span> results in total <span id="total_count"></span> 
</span>
```

Credit: beNiceWeAlLearning

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `getDataCount` function to get a count of all rows in the table:

```js
var rowCount = table.getDataCount();
```